# vba/sas - Proc import csv creates problems when SAS is run through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I have written the following VBA code to automate SAS processes.

```
  Rem Start the SAS server
  Dim SASws As SAS.Workspace
  Dim SASwsm As New SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager
  Dim strError As String
  Set SASws = SASwsm.Workspaces.CreateWorkspaceByServer _
    ("MySAS", VisibilityProcess, Nothing, "", "", strError)
  Dim code_location As String, code_name As String, param_str As String
  Dim param_flag As Boolean
  code_location = "file:" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("B2").Value
  code_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("C2").Value
  param_flag = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("C4").Value
  If param_flag = True Then
  param_str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("D5").Value
  Else: param_str = "ds=Sasuser.Export_output"
  End If

  Rem Run the stored process
  Dim SASproc As SAS.StoredProcessService
  Set SASproc = SASws.LanguageService.StoredProcessService
  SASproc.Repository = code_location
  SASproc.Execute code_name, "ds=Sasuser.Export_output"
  'SASproc.Repository = "file:C:\Duopa_Repository\SAS_Codes\Weekly"
  'SASproc.Execute "weekly_refresh_run.sas", "ds=Sasuser.Export_output"

  Rem Shut down the SAS server
  SASwsm.Workspaces.RemoveWorkspaceByUUID SASws.UniqueIdentifier
  SASws.Close
  Set SASws = Nothing
```

All the SAS codes seem to work through this except the ones that import csv files using proc import method. Can someone please explain me why

Thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of notes on your code: 1) `Rem` is deprecated, use `'` to indicate a comment. 2) Indenting your code so you can **see** nesting levels will help immeasurably. A good tool like [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/) will do that and many other things for you. (Disclaimer: avid fan of RD, and starting to contribute to the project.)

Comment: What kind of issue are you running into with your code? Are you getting an error? If so, which one and on what line? Is it running "successfully" but not doing what you expect? If so, what _is_ happening?

Comment: You might want to include your SAS code also, in addition to what the error/issue is.